# JQ - Collect the amount of items and use the result in an IF sentence

Tags: json, jq

I have an expression in JQ that looks like this:

```
[{  "names": .products[] | .name }]  |  length  > 200 as $qty |  if ($qty) then "ok" else "not ok" end
```

I pretend to save a boolean value inside of "qty". And it does. But when I add the If I get no syntax error but I get that boolean value as a result insted of "ok" or "not ok".

What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I do this:

```
 ( [{  "names": .products[] | .name }]  |  length  > 200 ) as $qty |  if ($qty) then "ok" else "not ok" end
```

to improve the readability of the expression I get a syntax error telling me there is an "unexpected ) symbol"

Comment: It is not clear, do you want one `"ok"` / `"not ok"` as a summation or want it for each of the satisfying condition

Comment: It's hard to test without sample data, but you are definitely missing parens for the variable binding in the first snippet. Always use `(…) as $var`, as you did in the second snippet, which [seems to work](https://jqplay.org/s/iZiw7AO4_h7) with some sample data made up by myself.

Comment: @Inian I want only one string for the entire data. Its either "ok" or not "ok"

Comment: See the linked snippet in pdf's comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable that's immediately read again doesn't gain you anything. Just use the value directly:

```
[{ names: .products[] | .name }]
| length  > 200
| if (.) then "ok" else "not ok" end
```

Or maybe more expressive:

```
[{ names: .products[] | .name }]
| if (length  > 200) then "ok" else "not ok" end
```

And since wrapping the value in an object doesn't change the output, it can be simplified to one of these two:

```
.products | if (length > 200) then "ok" else "not ok" end
```

```
if(.products | length > 200) then "ok" else "not ok" end
```

You might also be interested in the [`-e` flag](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#invoking-jq) to jq, which sets the exit code based on the result of your filters:

> Sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output value was neither `false` nor `null`, 1 if the last output value was either false or null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.